# How to produce a figure dash ‒ (U+2012) with pdflatex and XCharter

Tags: pdftex, punctuation, unicode

How to produce the figure dash ‒ (corresponding unicode character U+2012) with pdflatex?

(The figure dash is used to separate digits, e.g. in a phone number.)

I am using the XCharter package for fonts.

Comment: Did you try `--` as usual in TeX?

Comment: Yes. This works and produces an n-dash. Not a figure dash.

Comment: As far as I can see, even the OpenType version of the XCharter font lacks U+2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `\fdash` command that produces a horizontal line of appropriate length.

```
\newlength\figurewidth
\newcommand\fdash
  {\settowidth\figurewidth{9}%
   \raisebox{0.6ex}{\makebox[\figurewidth]{\hrulefill}}%
  }
```

By measuring the width of `9` in the current font it adapts to the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\figurewidth
\newcommand\fdash
  {\settowidth\figurewidth{9}%
   \raisebox{0.6ex}{\makebox[\figurewidth]{\hrulefill}}%
  }
\newcommand\test
   {\noindent
    123456789\\
    1234\fdash6789\\
    - -- \fdash\ ---%
    \bigskip\par
   }
\begin{document}
\test
{\ttfamily\test}
{\tiny\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]