# How do I turn off phone number detection in TeXShop?

Tags: mac, texshop

Preface:  I think TeXShop is the best PDF viewer on the Mac, and I use it as my default PDF viewer.  But I also write math papers on it.

My Mac loves to find phone numbers even where they don't exist.  Way too often, I click on a mathematical figure in the PDF of a paper I'm writing in TeXShop, and a pop-up appears asking me if I want to call a certain "phone number" (constructed from the digits in my figure) in FaceTime.  Even if I don't click but only "hover", I get little pop-up notices mentioning the "phone numbers" it has found.  I have done a bit of poking around on the web and I see a lot of frustration but few answers except a vague sense that this can be turned off if specific applications allow it, and that somehow this has to do with the Edit -> Substitution menu.  (However, everything in that submenu is unchecked, including "Data Detection", which I assume is the relevant thing.)

Is there a way to stop this?  Or is my question an implied feature request for TeXShop?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335503/how-to-produce-a-figure-dash-u2012-with-pdflatex-and-xcharter (replacing dash with a rule).

Comment: I know this is specifically a TeXShop question, but a more general question has been asked elsewhere:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/419499/54943

Comment: I would ask the texshop maintainer.

Comment: Ok... I'm seeing something simliar in the Preview of a PDF. I also see this in Preview so I expect it's a system wide things. In Preview there doesn't seem to be a way to turn it off and in TeXShop the Edit->Substitutions->Data Detectors seems to be tied to the Source rather than Preview window (or both).

Comment: Googling shows there's a "Smart Links" option setting that regexes for stuff. System-wide settings are under "Preferences" aren't they? I don't use macs.

Comment: @Cicada:  Yes, the hope would be that there would be a system-wide way to turn this off.  But I have googled and seen some people expressing frustration that such a thing doesn't exist.  I certainly can't find it.

Comment: @Cicada:  Yes, the hope would be that there would be a system-wide way to turn this off.  But I have googled and seen some people expressing frustration that such a thing doesn't exist.  I certainly can't find it.

Comment: @HerbSchulz:  Yes, the lack of this in Preview is frustrating too.  But I don't think Apple doesn't pay much attention to their PDF front end.  That's one of the reasons I think TeXShop might be the best PDF viewer for Mac.  (Hopefully Apple stays on top of their core PDF rendering services, which are used by TeXShop and other things.)

Comment: @HerbSchulz:  The idea that Edit->Substitutions->Data Detectors is dealing with only the source window is probably an important clue.